# Python MySQL Connector: Can't connect to server with SSL

Tags: python, mysql, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a secured MySQL instance. I can connect to this server from this machine using SSL from other tools, including MySQL Workbench and MySQL Shell.

However, when I connect using the default connection arguments:

```
currdb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="hostname",
    user="user",
    password="hunter2",
    port=3306 )
```

knowing that my server is configured with

```
require_secure_transport = 1
```

I get a server error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 3159 (HY000): Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.
```

Per the [MySQL Connector documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html), the connector should attempt an SSL connection first, then fall back to an insecure connection. So evidently the SSL connection is failing with no explanation.

How do I troubleshoot the failed SSL connection when I know it's working for other tools on the same machine?

Python version: `3.7.2`

MySQL Server version: `5.7.30`

MySQL Connector version: `2.2.9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to provide these flags:

ssl_ca      File containing the SSL certificate authority.

ssl_cert        File containing the SSL certificate file.

ssl_key     File containing the SSL key.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't expect it to be so simple. I just needed to provide those with no value and the connection worked.